# Simplest way to display each hour of the day in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a calendar screen where I want to display the hours of the day like this:

```
12:00am

1:00am

2:00am

..

4:00pm

5:00pm

etc.
```

Being a total Ruby noob, I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out the simplest way to display this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate these like this:

```
array = ['12:00am'] + (1..11).map {|h| "#{h}:00am"} + ['12:00pm'] + (1..11).map {|h| "#{h}:00pm"}
```

or simply write out the array (this is more efficient):

```
array = ["12:00am", "1:00am", "2:00am", "3:00am", "4:00am", "5:00am", "6:00am", "7:00am", "8:00am", "9:00am", "10:00am", "11:00am", "12:00pm", "1:00pm", "2:00pm", "3:00pm", "4:00pm", "5:00pm", "6:00pm", "7:00pm", "8:00pm", "9:00pm", "10:00pm", "11:00pm"]
```

You can then print these however you want, eg.

```
array.each do |el|
    puts el
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# without using actual `Date` objects ...

p ["12:00am"] + (1..11).map {|h| "#{h}:00am"}.to_a + 
  ["12:00pm"] + (1..11).map {|h| "#{h}:00pm"}.to_a

["12:00am", "1:00am", "2:00am", "3:00am", "4:00am", "5:00am", "6:00am",
"7:00am", "8:00am", "9:00am", "10:00am", "11:00am", "12:00pm", "1:00pm",
"2:00pm", "3:00pm", "4:00pm", "5:00pm", "6:00pm", "7:00pm", "8:00pm",
"9:00pm", "10:00pm", "11:00pm"]
```

Or using actual `DateTime` objects and `%I:%M%p` as [format](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2255):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "Date"

for hour in 0..23 do
  d = DateTime.new(2010, 1, 1, hour, 0, 0)
  p d.strftime("%I:%M%p")  
end
```

Which would print:

```
"12:00AM"
"01:00AM"
"02:00AM"
"03:00AM"
"04:00AM"
"05:00AM"
"06:00AM"
"07:00AM"
"08:00AM"
"09:00AM"
"10:00AM"
"11:00AM"
"12:00PM"
"01:00PM"
"02:00PM"
"03:00PM"
"04:00PM"
"05:00PM"
"06:00PM"
"07:00PM"
"08:00PM"
"09:00PM"
"10:00PM"
"11:00PM"
```